# React custom hook using only useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I created a custom hook that uses useEffect to update a redux store when certain values in the store change:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { index } from '../actions'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import { omit } from 'lodash'

const selectPerformanceSearch = createSelector(
  state => omit(state.eventSearch, ['results', 'isFetching']),
  items => items
)

export default function useEventSearch() {
  const state = useSelector(selectEventSearch)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const initialFetch = useRef(true)
  const { tags, near, filters } = state
  const { lng, lat, location } = near

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialFetch.current) {
      const data = { tags, lng, lat, filters }
      dispatch(index('/event/search', 'EVENT_SEARCH', data))
    }
  }, [tags, lng, lat, filters, dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialFetch.current && location) {
      initialFetch.current = false
      const data = { lng, lat }
      dispatch(index('/event/closest', 'EVENT_SEARCH', data))
    }
  }, [lng, lat, location, dispatch])
}
```

Then I have a React component that uses the hook like so:

```
import useEventSearch from '../../hooks/usePerformanceSearch'

const SearchBar = props => {
  // ...code

  usePerformanceSearch()

  /// ...other code
  return ( ... )
}
```

It all works as I would expect but is it ok to just call and use a hook the way I did?

Comment: Your custom hook is also using `useSelector`, `useDispatch`, and `useRef`. But yeah, I think it is ok. Looks like it'll be called every render, but I think that is what you're going for anyway.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you! I clarified that I'm not only using useEffect.